# Can i use SqlDependency to update DGV if any data updating happen?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqldependency

I made my winform application with C#, and i use entity framework 5. I use also MySql to my DB.
i like to have my DGV always updated  and displa ythe "newest" data. 
To use SqlDependency is the best way to update any control if there is a modification happened on DB's data?
Thank  you to advice me?

Comment: Asking for "the best way" makes this question off-topic (too broad).

Comment: ok, let's say " MySqlDependency can resolve my problem?".

Comment: Then the answer is simply: yes. But why would you ask that anyway? That's what SqlDependency was made for.

Comment: My problem is that i use Mysql and can't find the sqldependency for Mysql.

Comment: So what's the equivalent of SqlDependency on Mysql ?